# Full text search in laravel 4 across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a project which I am working on which requires full text searching on multiple tables in a database. I found a useful tutorial here:

http://creative-punch.net/2013/12/implementing-laravel-4-full-text-search

I have got it to work on one table, but now wish to extend to more than one. The issue I am having is that; if duplicate what is there for the remainder of the tables, when I hit submit, how do I get the button to check more than one controller ? or modify existing controller to check multiple tables ?

code

default view form

```
<div class="search">
    {{ Form::model(null, array('route' => array('search'))) }}
    {{ Form::text('query', null, array( 'placeholder' => 'Search query...' )) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Search') }}
    {{ Form::close() }} 
</div>
```

returned view

```
<div class="search">
    {{ Form::model(null, array('route' => array('search'))) }}
    {{ Form::text('query', null, array( 'placeholder' => 'Search query...' )) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Search') }}
 @foreach($posts as $post)
    <li>{{ $post->instance_id }}</li>
    <li>{{ $post->instance_type }}</li>
    <li>{{ $post->availability_zone }}</li>
    <li>{{ $post->status_checks }}</li>
    <li>{{ $post->alarm_status }}</li>
    <li>{{ $post->public_dns }}</li>
    <li>{{ $post->key_name }}</li>
 @endforeach
{{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

controller class

```
<?php 
class PostsController extends BaseController {

public function postSearch(){
    $q = Input::get('query');

   $posts =     ec2_instance::whereRaw("MATCH(instance_id,instance_type,availability_zone, status_checks,alarm_status, public_dns, key_name ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 
        array($q))->get();
        View::share('posts', $posts);

    return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('posts'));

}
}
?>
```

my initial thought is to modify the controller such that you add :

```
 $ip_address = public_ip::whereRaw("MATCH(ip_address) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN      MODE)",     
         array($q))->get();'
```

then in the view add

```
     @foreach($ip_address as $ip)
         <li>{{ $ip->ip_address}}</li>
     @endforeach
```

however variable ip_address could not be found

Comment: Please, use punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was returning 2 views which is not possible do as per my initial thoughts ensuring you only return 1 view ie

```
$posts = ec2_instance::whereRaw("MATCH(instance_id,instance_type,availability_zone, status_checks,alarm_status, public_dns, key_name ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q))->get();



 $ip_address =
 public_ip::whereRaw("MATCH(ip_address ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",           array($q))->get();


$s3_bucket = 
 s3_bucket::whereRaw("MATCH(name, storage_class, size ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q))->get();

 $cloudfront_distribution =    cloudfront_distribution::whereRaw("MATCH(delivery_method, cloudfront_id, domain_name,comment, origin, c_name, status, state ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q))->get();

return View::make('ec2_instance', compact('ip_address', 'posts','s3_bucket', 'cloudfront_distribution'));
```